# Can a deleted activeRecord instance be recovered in yii2?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I have a general question regarding yii2 ActiveRecord model.
When an instance of the ActiveRecord model is deleted, am I able to recover it?

Comment: No you can not recover it, But instead of hard delete you can user flag like is_deleted

Comment: you dont delete it actually but **mark** it as delete if you need to implement such scenario in your application where you need to restore

Answer (score 2):

The answer is depends.

I don't know what you need, but generally you cannot recover a deleted row from the DB. What you can do is what @YasinPatel recommended - add a new column `is_deleted` and instead of `Model::delete()` you can set `is_deleted` to `true`. Then in the other logic do not handle rows with `is_deleted == true`. In this case, the rows aren't really deleted, but they can appear so. Again, I am do not know your exact case.

In the rare cases where you want to delete something, maybe to call some events or something, what you can do is run a delete in a transaction and then revert it. You probably aren't asking for this and do not need it, but I believe it is good to be aware it exists.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on situation.

If the record has been deleted by something like `$model->delete()` and you still have the instance `$model` than you can do `$model->save()` to restore it, because even after deletion the instance of $model still have the values of attributes before deletion.

If you've already lost the instance of `$model` or if you never had it in first place (for example because the delete has been done using something like `Model::deleteAll($condition)` then you can't recover it using this approach.

This also won't recover any related records that might be removed by `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

If you need to recover record in different request than the one that deleted it. You can store `$model` in session then get it from there and do `$model->save()`
For example like this:

```
public function actionDelete()
{
    $model = Author::findOne(2);
    $model->delete();

    Yii::$app->session->set('model', $model);
}

public function actionRestore()
{
    if (Yii::$app->session->has('model')) {
        $model = Yii::$app->session->get('model');
        $model->save();
    }
}
```